# How is the method/means of performing an action expressed?

Tags: traducción

En inglés, se usa la palabra "*by*" para decir frases como "*study by reading*," en la cual "*by reading*" significa la manera en que la acción está logrado.

Si quisiera decir algo como "*I helped him by giving him something*," por ejemplo, ¿cómo lo traduciría? ¿Diría "*lo ayudé por darle algo a él*," o "*lo ayudé dándole algo a él*," u otra cosa?

---

In English, the word "*by*" is used to say phrases like "*study by reading*," where "*by reading*" signifies the manner in which the action is achieved.

If I wanted to say something like "*I helped him by giving him something*," for example, how would I translate that? Would I say "*lo ayudé por darle algo a él*," or "*lo ayudé dándole algo a él*," or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La traducción correcta sería tu segunda opción: "lo ayudé dándole algo" pero suprimiendo el "*a él*" por redundante, al  estar ya incluido en dándo**le**.

---

The correct translation would be your second choice : "lo ayudé dándole algo" but supressing the final "*a él*", as it is included in *"dándo**le**"*.

Answer (score 2):

Efectivamente, como la respuesta anterior ya aclaró, lo correcto sería "lo ayudé dándole algo". Además, si volvemos al primer que diste ("study by reading"), la traducción correcta sería usando el gerundio del verbo: "estudiar leyendo".

---

Indeed, as stated in the previous answer, the correct translation would be "lo ayudé dándole algo." Furthermore, going back to your first example ("study by reading"), the correct translation would use the continuous tense: "estudiar leyendo."